# Cpanel remote or timed killswitch

Tags: cron, cpanel, remote-access, shutdown

Is there a way to shutdown Cpanel or all websites remotely or in base of a cron?

This is useful when you work on someone elses hosted account and they forget or delay payment or maybe refuse to pay at all, after months lost working for them.

Or maybe another way to delete or scramble your work after the user changes the Cpanel password.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the CSS style on an external server, for example.

Comment: accessing a second domain's files first to get the CSS needed would delay unacceptably the rendering of the main website.